# Procedural texture shows up in eevee/viewport shading but not cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, baking

I've made a procedural texture, and I want to bake it, but the texture doesn't show up in cycles. Here it is in cycles:

[image]

And here it is in viewport shading/eevee:

[image]

And here is my nodes:

[image]

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: this sould normally work, id say. can you share a simplified file. For example a cube with the procedural material?

Comment: Sure! in a bit. I gave myself an injury I need to take care of

Comment: Hi :). Any chance of a duplicate mesh covering the result?

Comment: not really, there are no duplicate meshes. also it changes when I change the nodes. There are also some weird effects that might be insightful. When I separate the XYZ of the tangent and only use two of the three coordinates, it shows up. But not with all 3. Also I get the same effect using the tangent instead of the cross product.